# What error should be thrown when a class passed in as a parameter has an incorrect property?

Tags: c#

I have in `Insert` method that expects to receive a `ClientList` with no Id set (as if the list has an id set it should be updated not inserted again). Should this method throw an `ArgumentException` when `ClientList.Id.HasValue` or is there something more semantic?

Comment: This seems more an error tied to your logic. It is probably better to have your own derived Exception class.

Comment: One could possibly argue for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, although that's more a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Of the in built subclasses of [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.ArgumentException.aspx) there is nothing that fits this use case.

You could add your own custom exception subclass if the callers would benefit from more detail in properties of the exception (rather than just putting the information in the message).

Otherwise just use `ArgumentException`